# Evaluate using series

Tags: calculus

Evaluate using power series:
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3-3x+5arctan(x)}{6x^5}$.

I tried changing arctan(x) to $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ and factoring by x^5 but I find that the limit does not exist and I don't have the answer to the question. If the limit exists can someone explain how in a way that first year calculus 2 student can understand.

Comment: Isn't it $x\to 0$?

Comment: The interesting limit would be $lim_{x\to 0}(x^3-3x+3\arctan x)/6x^5$. There are at least two typos, I am pretty sure.

Comment: you guys are right, it is x-> 0 I had trouble using Math.jax in the series it is also x^(2n+1) I don't know why it looks that way

Comment: You need curly brackets around the exponent. Also, your coefficient in front of arctan should be 3, not 5.

Comment: It is 5 in the actual question though

Comment: Strange. In that case, the limit is just $+\infty$, since the numerator is linear near $x=0$.

Comment: Alright thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes familiarity with L'Hôpital's rule and inverse trigonometic functions.

We have

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^3-3x+5\arctan(x)}{6x^5}$$
The numerator and denominator both evaluate to $0$ at $x=0$, so use L'Hôpital's rule :
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^3-3x+5\arctan(x)}{6x^5} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{ \frac{d}{dx}
(x^3-3x+5\arctan(x))}{\frac{d}{dx}(6x^5)} =  \lim_{x\to0} \frac{ 
3x^2-3+5(\frac{1}{1+x^2})}{30x^4}.$$

The numerator evaluates to $2$ and the denominator to $0$, so it is undefined. (More precisely, it diverges)